# Get values of 2 columns as single value separated with '|'

Tags: sql

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Column1 VARCHAR(1),Column2 VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('1','2'),('-','2'),('1','2'),('-','-'),('2','-'),('1','2');

SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(Column1 + '|','-|'),'')
      +ISNULL(NULLIF(Column2,'-'),'')
FROM @mockup
```

Above query result is as below,

```
1|2
2
1|2
2|
1|2
```

I want the result as above only except row4, where 2| should be only as 2 .
'|' should not be there at before or end of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join both fields and use `REPLACE` to remove `|-` and `-|`. Condition in `WHERE` clause avoids records where both fields are `-`:

```
select replace(replace(Column1+'|'+Column2,'-|',''),'|-','') as Result
from mockup
where coalesce(nullif(Column1,'-'),nullif(Column2,'-')) is not null
```

Output:

```
Result
1|2
2
1|2
2
1|2
```

See result [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9e302/21).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replace` function

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(Column1 + '|' + Column2,'-|',''),'|-',''),'-','')
FROM @mockup
```

or try using `CASE` statement

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN column1 LIKE '[0-9]' AND column2 LIKE '[0-9]' THEN column1 + '|' + column1 
         WHEN column1 LIKE '[0-9]' AND column2 NOT LIKE '[0-9]' THEN column1 
         ELSE column2 
       END 
FROM   @mockup
```

if you want to check the `-` instead of numbers then

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN column1 NOT LIKE '-'  AND column2 NOT LIKE '-' THEN column1 + '|' + column1 
         WHEN column1 NOT LIKE '-'  AND column2 LIKE '-' THEN column1 
         ELSE column2 
       END 
FROM   @mockup
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
select stuff( ((case when column1 not like '-' then '|' + column1 else '' end) +
               (case when column2 not like '-' then '|' + column2 else '' end)
              ), 1, 1, '');
```

This is the simplest way that I've found to implement `concat_ws()` in SQL Server.  `concat_ws()` is a function available in other databases, where you would just do:

```
select concat_ws('|',
                 (case when column1 not like '-' then column1 end),
                 (case when column2 not like '-' then column2 end)                 
                )
```